# After a backslash did its work

Tags: syntax

A rather puny question:
What is "good practice" to end a backslashed command?
At the moment, I simply insert a `{}` if the following char
(can you tell me which ones qualify?) does not automatically end the
backslashed command, e.g. `$\rho+\Delta{}A$`. In this case, the
closing bracket could go after the A but I quickly found
that when expressions get complicated (e.g. A has an index 1
too) things go unmatched very fast :-)

Comment: In math mode never use `{}` this way (it will ruin the spacing in general) just use a space.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Never use braces just to terminate a command in math mode, they form an empty node, rather like `\mbox{}` and so affect the space. In your example just use

```
$\rho+\Delta A$
```

An example with a clear spacing difference would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\rho \leq{} + 2 A$

$\rho \leq + 2 A$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This same example also shows we can't use `{}` around the macro either, as in `{\leq}` (stating just in case anyone was considering that option for delimiting macros).

Answer (score 2):

In general all letters qualify to follow a backslash and make up a command name. These letters are a-z and A-Z by default. Some commands like `\makeatletter` or `\ExplSyntaxOn` add other characters as letters (e.g. `@` or `_` and `:`). If one of those characters follows the command name you have to put some boundary there. The easiest way to do this is to follow your command by a space (as mentioned by @DavidCarlisle).

Examples (if you want more details consider reading [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/379760/124577)):

```
\DeltaA % this would be one command, use
\Delta A % instead as this has the "boundary", but
\Delta1 % would not be a problem as 1 is no "letter" by default
\Delta@ % see above, but
\makeatletter\Delta@\makeatother % would call for a macro \Delta@
```

If math mode is concerned you are done using the space. In text mode you may want to consider that the space after a command is absorbed. So in text mode you may want to use `\textDelta{}` (or if you want to ensure the space `\textDelta\`).